# getting an error while doing thresholding Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new in OpenCv im doing thresholding  of my grayscale image but it shows an error ie **TypeError: Expected Ptr for argument '%s'**

```
grey = cv2.cvtColor(o, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh1 = cv2.threshold(cv2.UMat(grey),127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("thresh1",thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `_, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(grey,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` should work.

Comment: `thresh1 = cv2.threshold(cv2.UMat(grey),127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]` is another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need cv2.UMat(grey), only the image.

```py
import cv2
grey = cv2.cvtColor(o, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
a, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(grey, 127, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("thresh1",thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```